# estimate the divergence between two distributions by comparing the sufficient statistics

Tags: sufficient-statistics, divergence

I'm interested in comparing two distributions $p(x,y)$ and $q(x,y)=pr(x)q(y|x)$.

I want to estimate the KL-divergence between $p(x,y)$ and $q(x,y)$. It could be other divergence too, and I'm happy to know if there is any nice results on that. Now, suppose I only have many samples, $x_i$ draw from $pr(x)$, and two sufficient statistics $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ for $p(y|x)$ and $q(y|x)$ respectively. By the definition of sufficient statistics, we have
$$y\rightarrow f(x)\rightarrow x ~\mbox{ and }~ y\rightarrow g(x)\rightarrow x, $$
as two Markov Chains. Here $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both deterministic functions of $x$.

Would it be possible to come up with some approximation of $KL(p(x,y) || q(x,y))$ using samples $x_i$, and the two functions $f(x)$, $g(x)$?

----------(Updated)--------

Sorry I shouldn't have introduced $pr(x)$. I hope the following description is better.

Let $x$ be the data, $y$ the label. $y$ can be understood as some hidden variable that control the generation of $x$, via $p(x|y)$ and $q(x|y)$ respectively. I'm interested in estimating $KL(p(x,y)||q(x,y))$. Or perhaps, $KL(p(x|y)||q(x|y))$, if we don't care the prior on $y$.

Let $f(x)$ be a function of $x$, so this process is $y\rightarrow x \rightarrow f(x)$, as a Markov chain. Further assume $f(x)$ is a sufficient statistics of $x$ for $y$ when the generative process is $p(x|y)$ (check Thomas Cover's elements of Information Theory). That is to say, $y\rightarrow f(x) \rightarrow x$ is also a Markov chain, when the generative process has conditional probability $p(x|y)$.

Likewise, let function g(x) be the sufficient statistics of $x$ for $y$ when the generative process is $q(x|y)$.

The question is, can we relate $KL(p(x,y)||q(x,y))$ (or perhaps $KL(p(x|y)||q(x|y))$) to the two sufficient statistics, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$?

Comment: This is the most confusing question I have read in a while: if $pr$ denotes a _prior_, it is a distribution on the parameter space, for which _sufficiency_ does not apply. The relation between $y\sim p(y|x)$ and $f(x)$ is undefined. The graph $y→f(x)→x$ does not connect with _Markov chains_ in a standard way.

Comment: @Xi'an Sorry I shouldn't have introduced (). See the updated question.

Comment: It remains unclear how to relate both concepts: even if $p$ and $q$ share the same sufficient statistic, $f(x)$, the conditionals $p(x|f(x))$ and $q(x|f(x))$ may still differ.

Comment: Sure, I understand this may not have been studied in literature. Indeed, even if $f(x)=g(x)$, it doesn't lead to $p(x|y)=q(x|y)$. But I'm curious if we could say anything more about the relationship between $distance(f, g)$ and $distance(p, q)$.